# Accessing Page Class From Another Page Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I access a page class from another class. For example I have:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
}
```

Why can I not access it from another class in App_Code folder?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() {}
    public void DoSomething(object o)
    {
         // The following line won't compile.
         MyPage page = o as MyPage;
    }
}
```

---

I just figured it out (thanks to Fujiy) that for some reason this is the case with website project, but is not a problem with web application project in VS. If anyone has any clues as to why, please share your thoughts. Thank you :)

Comment: @anna: post it as an answer - I think you're right.

Comment: yeah me too, I just dumped it to VS to check for anything non-obvious :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code as posted, most likely you've got a **namespace** problem.

edit: gah, just noticed that you mentioned this was a website project. It's been a while since I deigned to start one of those :) but I believe this stems from the fact that App_Code is run-time compiled. It would take a better man than me to explain *why* that creates the problem, but long story short I'd just avoid website projects in general.

Comment: Code as posted works, must be namespace or you've a typo in your actual code.

Comment: I get this error: The type or namespace name 'MyPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Just created a new project to check if it will work - it doesn't. The namespaces are non-existent.

Comment: In a website project, the namespaces are implicit based on the site structure.  You'd need to explicitly identify the full path to the class you want to access, using "." instead of "/"...

Comment: @niaher - one of them is definitely in another namespace *somehow* I think your clearest way through is to check the object browser and/or put them in a namespace. Namespaces are good and intellisense is very good about helping you with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, afaik:

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
```

Be careful where you call that though, because obviously at different points in your code the page won't be available. For example, Application_Start in global.asax.